# How to focus addons icons in the toolbar in Firefox via keyboard?

Tags: firefox, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions

To get to the addons on my Firefox's toolbar, I have to point and click on their icons to open their menus or dialog boxes

[image: scr]

I want to focus these various add-on's icons that are actually in the toolbar, so that I can access their respective option menus that opens up when you click them with the mouse.

I'm trying to find a **keyboard-only** way to get to them.

I tried <kbd>Tab</kbd>-ing from address bar, but it never takes the focus to the addon icons.

Is there a way to get to those addons, open their menus etc, all via keyboard only?

Some of the addons do have their menus in Tools menu, but not all of them.

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + N opens the NoScript menu,

Comment: See https://noscript.net/features. You can change the shortcut.